# Tools for checking spring performance and bottlenecks with example

Tags: java, performance, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am new to all this performance improvement thing. Can anyone provide names of some good tools or techniques for checking the performance of the web application and finding the bottlenecks in the application both on server side and client side. If any one can provide link examples or tutorials to such tools or techniques it will be very helpful. Thanks in advance for your help.

Using VisualVM i got following result

[image: VisualVM Memory Profiler for my Web application]

please do let me know how to find the code in my application which is responsible for this.

Comment: Didn't you forget to close your object streams? They're eating the memory. Maybe you'll need to reset them from time to time, as otherwise they remember all objects going though forever.

Comment: Which object streams you are asking for reset. I have an web application. Can you please let me know which type of object stream should be closed and at what part of the application. If you can provide any link to the document or info where i can understand this properly it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: The fourth row shows `ObjectStreamClass$WeakClassKey` so I suppose you're using a object streams a lot. The third row might be related as well. But I have no idea about what are you or your framework doing, it was just a guess based on the scarce information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving the performance of a web application involves couple of things.

Improving the application code involves :

- Apply caching - E.g. JCS, EHCache
- Compression of HTTP requests
- Avoid Embedding of Javascripts
- Balance the load - Horizontal/Vertical Scaling
- Cookie size reduction

Use profiling tools like **JProfiler, jProbe, JRockit, VisualVM**

**EDITED** for the changed question :

Are you getting Out of memory Error ?
To find Memory related issue, Take snapshot at regular interval and look for possible leaks. Using the **Deltas mode**  you can easily watch newly allocated and disposed objects over a specific period of time or while an action is executed which makes it really easy to identify a memory leak. Also, the memory data can be saved as a .nps snapshot which can later be compared to other memory snapshots using the Compare function. Once the memory leak is identified, you can investigate the leak further by using the built-in HeapWalker. The HeapWalker has been enhanced to support displaying retained sizes and provides a powerful OQL scripting engine.

Furthermore, you can use other tools for heap analysis like :

- [HAT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html), The Java Heap Analysis Tool
- YourKit Java Profiler
- [Memory Analyzer project](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) at Eclipse, contributed to them by SAP.
- HeapWalker is a good option too.

Comment: Hi, i have edit my question and provided a memory profiler for my web application now the question is how do i find which part of application is responsible for it. If it has provided me some class name i have easily sort it out but when it provide such a result then what??

Comment: Are you getting a OOM error in your application ?

Comment: Yes when the users count increases to ~5-10 then it starts giving OOM errror.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `visualVM`, its free and powerful tool to track the J2EE performance application, some of its features:

- Provide a CPU profiling.
- Provide all info about Threads.
- Provide the JVM Heap and the memory states.
- Provide Info about the GC activities.

Its come with the JDK package, so you don't have to install it, for more info check [this](http://visualvm.java.net/)